# Origin of cusps in simulated dark matter halos

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dark-matter

I keep reading that cusps are one of the most "robust" predictions of N-body simulations of dark matter halos. But papers I've found on the topic make it sound like these simulations are complicated and slow and that the cusps are just an observed result of the simulations rather than that the cusps have some understandable physical origin. But my immediate reaction was that the cusps' origin is trivial (just the result of phase-space considerations) and that interaction-less dark matter simulations should be one of the easiest things in the world.

I remember writing a program to simulate non-interacting particles orbiting each-other with an inverse square law on an old PC over a decade ago, and I recall being able to get a pretty good picture of the density profile by tracing the paths of just a few particles. This only took a minute or two on a very slow PC. Indeed I remember something of a cusp being obvious, simply because the orbits of each particle tended to intersect near the CM, an effect that overrode the countervailing fact that individually each spent less time near the CM.

In fact, even without doing a simulation, I would assume this would be the case because Keplerian motion clearly indicates that the time spent near the CM drops close to linear in R while volume goes as R^3. Anyway, I'm just wondering if these observations are basically correct, or if the origin of the cusps is somehow more obscure/complicated.

Comment: My N-bodies made a swarm!

Comment: So, is your question: What are the origins of cuspy dark matter halos?

Comment: @astromax: what about my question is unclear? I am asking about the origins of the cusps (as opposed to cores) in dark matter halos. Not about the origins of the halos themselves. As I say in my question, it seems like the cuspy prediction is naively obvious and shouldn't require difficult simulations. I'm wondering if this is true or if there is some complication I am not aware of.

Comment: @user1247 Well, for one you don't actually ask a single question. Additionally, some of these simulations have millions or even billions of particles in them - why is it 'obvious' to you that you should be seeing cusps as opposed to cores. I may have a few answers once I know what you question is, because this is part of what I study.

Comment: @astromax: the last line of my post is a question. Additionally, I think I give a very detailed context in my post for exactly what I am asking, and why it is obvious to me that I should be seeing cusps. In fact, as I said in my post, I DID see cuspiness myself in my own small-N simulations trivially done on an old computer. Furthermore, in my post I mentioned a pretty trivial theoretical argument for cuspiness. My question, again, are the above observations correct, or not? If not, why not?

Comment: @astromax: in other words, my current assumption is that naively cuspiness is an obvious prediction without even doing simulations, but that the reason why simulations are now a big deal is because we don't see cuspiness in empirical data. So people are puzzled and trying to figure out a loophole...

Comment: First of all, what is your definition of a 'cusp'?

Comment: @astromax, a non-continuous first derivative (wrt r) of the density profile at the CM

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about this. It's the slope of the density profile in log-log space which people talk about when referring to "cuspy" vs. "cored" dm halos. An inner density profile of -1 is "cuspy". "Cored" halos have much flatter inner density profiles.

Comment: @astromax, I made a statement about the slope which is not necessarily dissimilar to yours, but I'm not an expert in this area obviously. My physics intuition stated in my post and my own observations of simple newtonian simulations indicate a qualitatively highly non-flat density profile near r=0. In any case my question is independent of all this. See the last sentence of my original post. The question is about the basic reasoning and use of very simple simulation. Is it correct or not? If not why not?

Comment: Well hold on, I'm first trying to understand your claim here based upon the simulation you said you performed. There may be some very important differences which lead you to make the claim that it is obvious that they should be cuspy, and that it's because of the physical argument you have provided. By the way, understanding why from a physics standpoint NFW profiles keep showing up in simulations over a very large range of mass scales is not something people have figured out yet - so if you think it's obvious, you should publish a paper on the subject. How many particles did you use, and

Comment: what masses did you use? Please provide more detail on the simulation you ran.

Comment: @astromax, OK you are saying I am wrong. That's what I was looking for! Next: why am I wrong? What about what I was doing was wrong? (see next comment). Although I'm also interested in what is wrong with the type of extremely basic theoretical argument I made up, and why such arguments can't be trusted.

Comment: @astromax, the simulation I did was very simple. I simulated N (as many as I could at the time on my PC, something like 100) point particles following Newtonian gravity. I used C++ and opengl. I released them from rest or with small random velocities at various points in a rectangular 3 dimensional grid. Then I watched. I also plotted the average density profile among other things. But just from watching a 2D projection of the orbits around the CM it was obvious there was something of a singularity, or what I have always understood to be cuspiness.

Comment: @astromax, I played with the timestep, but it was a long time ago and I don't think I can give further details. I'm a careful person and I trust myself that I varied the time step (and corresponding number of simulated particles, due to changes in simulation time) until I was sure that the observed physics was robust to small changes in the time step.

Comment: 100 particles is nowhere near enough to resolve halos on any scales except for maybe star clusters. I know your argument still stands, but I personally don't see how you could glean any sort of intuition about the inner slope in log-log space from your simulation.

Comment: @astromax, why would 100 particles, simulated for long enough, not be enough? What percent of a galaxy's mass is in the halo?

Comment: Well, in the case of clusters, the halo is about 85% the total mass, the ICM is about 10%, and the galaxies themselves are 5%. For galaxies it may differ a bit, but certainly the halo is the biggest component. 100 particles is not enough to resolve fine enough detail, and you'd ideally like sufficient detail to use for computing the radial profile. Even if you stare at 100 particles for the entire length of the simulation, your environment is considerably different from what it would have been if you included more particles. You may see an extremely dense inner region,

Comment: but remember they all look like that. Until you measure the slope (derivative) in log-log space to be at or near -1, it's hard for you to say whether or not it's cuspy or not. Usually simulations use at least 10's of thousands of particles to resolve structure to be able to make quantitative statements like that.

Comment: @astromax, what is the size (HWHM or something) of the cusp/core, and what is the definition of what separates a cusp from a core? I thought the difference was totally obvious: a core has a flat profile near r=0. Also what percent of a galaxy's mass is in the cuspy region (sorry I realize I mis-typed the same question in my last post -- the point is that 100 particles should easily be enough if the mass of the cuspy region is anything above something like ~1% percent of the total mass, and even then 0.1% would probably be OK).

Comment: Well the characteristic radius people talk about when discussing NFW density profiles is what's called the scale radius, which is the point where the profile (again plotted in log-log) goes as r^{-2}. 100 particles is simply not enough to resolve any structure on any scale of a halo.

Comment: @astromax, sorry but I'd rather not just take your word on this. The variable which I think determines whether 100 particles is or is not enough is the mass enclosed by the scale radius. If the mass enclosed by the scale radius is greater than 1%, then 100 particles should easily show cuspy behavior, since on average 1 particle will be inside the cuspy region, and all you have to do is wait long enough to populate a statistical sample in order to compare the profile inside that radius. In fact the mass inside the scale radius could be even less as long as you watched for long enough.

Comment: I think most people doing simulations will agree that 100 particles is clearly not enough to resolve galaxy scale dark matter halo formation. Having a single particle within the scale radius (and potentially not other times) seems like a very bad idea. Additionally, you have provided little to no information about how you've conducted your simulation. At this point discussing anything further would simply be conjecture.

Comment: @astromax, then thanks for your time, but apparently you can't answer my question, which is "why" rather than simply an appeal to authority. As implied in my OP I know already that for some reason 100 particles is understood to be not enough, but nonetheless you can see cuspy behavior when integrated over time...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has this entry about the [cuspy halo problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuspy_halo_problem)

> "The cuspy halo problem arises from cosmological simulations that seem to indicate cold dark matter (CDM) would form cuspy distributions — that is, increasing sharply to a high value at a central point — in the most dense areas of the universe. This would imply that the center of the Milky Way, for example, should exhibit a higher dark-matter density than other areas. However, it seems rather that the centers of these galaxies likely have no cusp in the dark-matter distribution at all.
>   "

I think the last sentence could be interpreted thus "... it seems from  actual astronomical observations and interpretations/models based on observations that... there should **not** be a cusp in DM density at the centre of a galaxy".

Thus it seems to me that your simulation (for whatever reason) agrees with more sophisticated simulations in predicting a cusp whereas actual astronomical observations suggest that there should not be a cusp.

Comment: The most popular explanation is that there is no cusp due to the presence of baryons which need hydrodynamic simulations to be accurately described.

Comment: @physicsphile So baryons influence DM?

Comment: Yes, via their gravitational attraction.

Answer (score -2):

Cusps are an obvious consequence of the usual DM models to me too.

It seems that there are so many problems with dark matter theory that something is obviously wrong.

We have the cusp problem, the lack of DM in the nearby region of of our galaxy, the failure to find any in experiments, and more.

By far the biggest problem with DM though is the complete lack of its prediction, given that we have so many smart theoreticians! Ditto of course on the dark energy front.

I really like how observational astronomy is working on the third decimal place of DM abundance. To physics however there is not even an acknowledgment of any problem.

I thought I was commenting ...

To turn this into an answer,

There is no need for complicated models to model the cusps, they come about when making models for the entire matter -DM structure.

Comment: I think those extra comments are not in line with stack exchange conventions and I suggest you remove them.